# jQuery.Deferred exception: XXX is not a function TypeError: XXX is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am chaining callbacks as shown in the following Javascript snippet below:

```
function market_price_cb(chart, marketdata){
    if (!chart.isEmpty()){
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // build chart from scratch ...                 
    }

    // do something with the chart ...
}


function my_chart_cb(chart, market_price_cb){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/123'
    }).then(function(data) {
        market_price_data = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(market_price_data);
        market_price_cb(chart, market_price_data);
    });
}


// Fetches chart JSON data from server and rebuilds chart object
function load_chart_from_server(symbol, data_freq, my_chart_cb)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/699',
        success: function (data) {
            let chart_object = $.parseJSON(data)
            console.log(chart_object);
            my_chart = new Chart(chart_object);

            my_chart_cb(my_chart);
        },
        async: true                 
    });
}
```

When I run the code on my page, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: market_price_cb is not a function

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yeah this is pretty obvious if you'er not providing the parameter how can there be a function

Comment: either do scope.market_price_cb or don't add the param. If you want to add it as optional do: if (market_price_cb){market_price_cb();} else {window.market_price_cb());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing the second argument to `my_chart_cb` call, thus `market_price_cb` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use this keyword to access the function "market_price_cb" in my_chart_cb().  It will solve the problem.

It means:

```
function my_chart_cb(chart, market_price_cb){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/123'
    }).then(function(data) {
        market_price_data = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(market_price_data);
        this.market_price_cb(chart, market_price_data);
    });
}
```